# Вопрос по static method и class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

1. Хочу утвердиться правильно ли я понимаю static method и class method.
   Если мы метод оборачиваем в декоратор `@staticmethod`, то объявленный метод не будет относиться ни к классу в котором мы его объявили, и объекту к которого мы создали, вопрос значит ли это что я могу написать этот метод как функцию в области модуля?
2. Если обернуть метод в декоратор `@classmethod`, то при вызове как я понимаю он будет влиять на все объекты созданные на основе этого класса. Ну например скажем есть поле count, который считает общее количество созданных объектов или я не так все понимаю?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Различие в том, какое значение будет неявно передано в метод в качестве дополнительного аргумента.

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def method1():
        print('static method')

    @classmethod
    def method2(cls):
        print('class method', cls)

    def method3(self):
        print('regular method', self)

a = A()
a.method1() # static method
a.method2() # class method <class '__main__.A'>
a.method3() # regular method <__main__.A object at 0x7f5ebe7d6128>
```

В `method1` не будет передано ничего лишнего, в `method2` будут передан только класс соответствующий экземпляру (`A`), а в `method3` - сам экземпляр (`a`).

Так как первые два метода не привязаны к конкретному экземпляру, их также можно вызывать от имени класса.

```py
A.method1() # static method
A.method2() # class method <class '__main__.A'>
```

Если попытаться таким образом вызвать `method3` это приведет к ошибке

```py
A.method3() # TypeError: method3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

В таком случае необходимо будет указать экземпляр явно

```py
A.method3(a) # regular method <__main__.A object at 0x7f0f9cda10b8>
```

Если метод, декорированный `classmethod`, будет унаследован, ему в качестве аргумента будет передан уже класс наследник

```py
class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
b.method2() # class method <class '__main__.B'>
B.method2() # class method <class '__main__.B'>
```

Что отличает его от метода, декорированного `staticmethod`, который ничего не знает о конкретном классе, от имени которого (или от имени экземпляра которого) его вызвали.

### Upd

Например, есть класс

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.arg!r})'
```

Наша задача в том, чтобы автоматически сохранять все создаваемые экземпляры класса в список, и впоследствии иметь возможность этот список получить. В первом приближении получаем такое решение:

```py
class A:
    _instances = []

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self.get_instances().append(self)

    @staticmethod
    def get_instances():
        return A._instances

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.arg!r})'

A(1)
A('test')
A(1 == 0)
print(A.get_instances()) # [A(1), A('test'), A(False)]
```

Здесь `get_instances` вызывается от имени экземпляра, это возможно благодаря декоратору `staticmethod`. Можно было бы обойтись без него, и вручную вызвать метод от имени класса `type(self).get_instances()`, но с декоратором код становится проще.

Проблемы начинаются, когда появляется класс наследник

```py
class B(A):
    pass

B(None)
print(B.get_instances()) # [A(1), A('test'), A(False), B(None)]
```

`B` не имеет собственного списка экземпляров, и просто выводит вышестоящий. Туда же добавляются и экземпляры `B`.

Перепишем решение, заменив список на словарь `(Класс, Список)`.

```py
class A:
    _instances = {}

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self.get_instances().append(self)

    @staticmethod
    def get_instances():
        return A._instances.setdefault(A, [])

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.arg!r})'

class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def get_instances():
        return B._instances.setdefault(B, [])

A(1)
A('test')
A(1 == 0)
print(A.get_instances()) # [A(1), A('test'), A(False)]

B(None)
print(B.get_instances()) # [B(None)]
```

Теперь все работает, но в каждом потомке нужно переопределять метод `get_instances`, это приводит к повторениям и увеличивает шанс допустить ошибку. Тут на помощь приходит `classmethod`

```py
class A:
    _instances = {}

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self.get_instances().append(self)

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls):
        return cls._instances.setdefault(cls, [])

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.arg!r})'

class B(A):
    pass

A(1)
A('test')
A(1 == 0)
print(A.get_instances()) # [A(1), A('test'), A(False)]

B(None)
print(B.get_instances()) # [B(None)]
```

Теперь любой класс потомок будет иметь собственный список экземпляров, а вся логика по поддержанию этих списков описана только в базовом классе.

Comment: Понял спасибо большое! А на каком нибудь реальном примере можешь привести, если не затруднит)))

Comment: _"любой класс потомок будет иметь собственный список экземпляров"_ - но лежать этот список будет в общем словаре в базовом классе?

Comment: @Qwertiy Верно. В качестве альтернативы можно создавать список `_instances` в каждом классе, но это потребует дополнительных действий в потомках, да и потеряется косвенная возможность централизованного доступа к спискам всех потомков. Еще можно было бы писать напрямую в `__dict__` класса, создавая в нем список из `__init__`, если его там еще нет, но у этого подхода тоже есть свои минусы.